# Helm Chart export command deprecated for OCI

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Helm recently removed command "helm chart export", does anyone know what the substitution for that?

We used to use it for our ACR registry.

```
helm registry login reponame login pass
helm chart pull reponame/chartname (changed to helm pull now)
helm chart export reponame/chartname -destination 'path'
```

Comment: did you get workaround for this we are also using helm chart export but now upgrading to helm 3.7.1 its not working

Answer (score 0):

Start from v3.7.0, helm chart commands were retired. Ref: https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.7.0

```
helm chart export has been removed
helm chart list has been removed
helm chart pull has been replaced with helm pull
helm chart push has been replaced with helm push
helm chart remove has been removed
helm chart save has been replaced with helm package
```