# What was "helm chart export" command doing in helm 3.6

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am upgrading my projects to helm 3.7 and the `helm chart export` command in no longer supported.
https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.7.0

Also there is no Documentation for versions previous to 3.7 available. I want to upgrade my project and need to know how to replace the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm Chart export command deprecated for OCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477668/helm-chart-export-command-deprecated-for-oci)

Comment: @Ri1a, No, its does not explain what 'helm chart export' does. Only that it is deprecated. That bit of information I know already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm chart export command was used to extract the helm chart to a specific destination after you pulled the helm chart image. On which destination you could then run for example `helm install`